# python bottle zombie process

Tags: python, python-3.5, bottle

When developing a bottle webapp with python 3.5, I regularly get a zombie process. I get this when using the auto-restart development mode.
The windows console still updates with the access logs, and the errors, but the program isn't running in foreground anymore, so I can't access it to use Ctrl+C.
The only way to kill this is to open the task manager and end the process manually.
If I don't kill it, it will still be listening on the port, and have precedence on a newly started process.
I haven't found a rule for when this happens, nor have I found a way to reproduce.

How can I avoid this multi-spawned zombie process?

Comment: Have you used the if \__name__ == '\__main__' before running the bottle app? or are you not using default server?

Comment: Using default server. I'll check later today for the main

Comment: @YoavGlazner: I just use run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)

Comment: Did you add the if \__name__ == '\__main__': run(...) ?